# Why group_by() not working with apply() function

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a matrix and want to calculate products of sequences for each column of a matrix by groups. First, each group corresponds to different numbers. Second, each column of the matrix should be computed separately too.

For example, for user **1** and **y** column, the number should be `1*1`; for user **2** and **y** column, the number should be `2*3*1`

I used `apply` with `group_by` but the output is incorrect.

```
#data
user<-c(1,1,2,2,2)
y<-c(1,1,2,3,1)
z<-c(2,2,3,3,3)
dt<-data.frame(user,y,z)
  user y z
1    1 1 2
2    1 1 2
3    2 2 3
4    2 3 3
5    2 1 3
```

The output below is not by user

```
 dt%>%group_by(user)%>% (function(x){apply(x[,2:3],2,prod)})
      y   z 
      6 108
```

Desired output ( you can remove the NA too. It does not matter whether adding a new column or not)

```
    [,1] [,2]
[1,]   NA   NA
[2,]    1    4
[3,]   NA   NA
[4,]   NA   NA
[5,]    6   27
```

Comment: First, You don't have a matrix, rather a data frame. Secondly, why do you need these `NA`s there? Are you try to ad this results as new columns to your data frame? I.e., wouldn't just `dt %>% group_by(user) %>% summarise_all(funs(prod))` be enough?

Comment: whether adding new columns or not is both ok.

Comment: Groups are only respected by other `dplyr` functions, such as `summarise` and `do`.